# Javascript-extract numbers from array using for and if

Tags: javascript

How can I extract the numbers from the array  2, 5, 9, 15, 0, 4. that are bigger than 3 and smaller than 10 using for and if

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: Hello Adrian welcome to stack overflow. If you haven't seen the how to ask page, here is a link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Can you please show what have you tried?

Comment: Typically for new learners like yourself we ask that you first try to solve the problem yourself, then post your code and we will help you from there. If you don't know where to start, please try to explain your confusion

Comment: We would be happy to help you.  Share your attempt with us and we can help you get it working.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Answer (score 1):

Just think about iterating through your given array and check each element if it matches your conditions.

If element matches your conditions push it into a new or helper array.
Do the same with non matching elements, just in case you need them somehow.
If there is no use for your non-matching elements just do nothing.

```
var arr = [2, 5, 9, 15, 0, 4];
var matchingArr = []; // array for values bigger 3 and smaller 10
var nonMatchingArr = []; // array for values smaller 3 and bigger 10
arr.forEach(function(e){
    if (e > 3 && e < 10) {
        matchingArr.push(e);
    } else {
        nonMatchingArr.push(e);
    } 
});
```